# GitLab CI Pipeline not triggered by push from runner

Tags: gitlab-ci

We use Gitlab CE. We have two repos / projects, one to store the source code, and the other one to build and store the package that we’ll deploy. We use a runner to push the changes in the former into the latter. This used to trigger the pipeline of the latter repo. Recently, a change was pushed to the latter repo manually, and since then the push from the runner doesn’t trigger the pipeline any more in the target repo (manual pushes still trigger the pipeline, also, the push in the runner runs flawlessly, and the commit appears in the target repo). I was not the one who created the setup, so I don’t know how to make the push from the runner trigger the pripeline (or, rather, why it doesn’t do it automatically).

As far as I understand, the push should trigger the pipeline wherever it comes from. So why doesn't it do so?

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the issue appeared because the user account to which the deploy key used in the target repo belonged to has been disabled. Creating a new key with an active user account solved the problem, the pipeline is triggered properly now.

Comment: Are you talking about actual deploy key with write enabled or a user key?